# Do I have to install Spyder whenever I create a new environment on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am doing an assignment for school and it requires me to use a yml file to create an environment for grading consistency.

Question is, when I installed a new environment, I have to install Spyder on that environment again.

This seems quite inefficient as you have to install Spyder for all the environment that you are using...

Why cannot Anaconda simply call Spyder from different environments?

Is there a way I can open Spyder from the base(root) environment and use that for a different environment without installing Spyder for each environment?

Comment: No, I don't believe this is correct. You don't need to install Spyder again. Spyder is just an IDE, it has no specific relation to virtual environment used

Comment: That is what I thought too as well...But whenever I make a new environment, button under the Spyder in the new environment always says "install" instead of "launch". I do not understand why Anaconda would do this. Seems very inefficient. I am not looking into the way where I launch Spyder from base environment and maybe change some setting.

Comment: *I am not looking into the way where I launch Spyder from base environment and maybe change some setting* well that is your other option - either activate your environment then run Spyder installed in that environment, or run Spyder from its own environment (doesn't have to be `base`) then tell it to use the environment you want to work with (which must include the `spyder-kernels` package if you want to use the console). You don't have to launch Spyder from Anaconda Navigator, it should be in your Start menu (assuming Windows).